# Is factorization modulo a product of primes an NP-hard problem?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factoring, hardness-assumptions

For example, let, $p$ and $q$ be two large prime numbers. We set $n = p \cdot q$.
Now, let $a \cdot b = c \pmod n$.
Given $c$ and $n$, is finding the factors $a$ and $b$ computationally difficult?

I can alternatively ask, is integer factorization modulo a product of primes an NP-hard problem?

Comment: Are you considering that $a$ and $b$ are primes smaller than $n$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Answer (score 3):

Your question has not a unique answer. In general case, finding $a,b$ is very simple. In this state, we can choose an arbitrary $b$(can be a prime number) and find the $a$ as follow:
$$a=c\cdot b^{-1} \pmod n.$$
Unfortunately, if you need that $a$ be prime, your question has no unique answer again. As an example, let $n=33$ and $c=20$. So we have:
$$7\cdot17=23\cdot31=20 \pmod{33}.$$

Comment: Note that a prime in Z is not necessarily prime in Z/nZ, and conversely.

Comment: @fkraiem: what does 'prime in Z/nZ' mean?  I suppose it could be given a natural meaning, but that seems to be 'a prime factor of n (possibly multiplied by a value relatively prime to n)'; and it'll take longer than this comment to explain what that is the natural meaning...

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani, you gave a very good example for your claim. Thank you very much.

But to find the factorization (either prime or non-prime), does it need to check all the numbers (within range), as you said "arbitrary b"? In case, n is very large (such as like modulo of RSA cryptosystem), it might be computationally infeasible to factorize and to find a and b. Am I right?

I really appreciate an answer :-)

Comment: @AbdullahGani: you don't need to factor $n$ to compute $b^{-1} \bmod n$ for arbitrary $b$.  The worse thing that could happen is that'll fail if $b$ happens not to be relatively prime to $n$ (which will essentially never happen if $n$ is an RSA modulus)

Comment: Should add that $b^{-1}\mod{n}$ is efficiently computable using the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @poncho https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element

Comment: Thank you. You guys are providing very crucial information for me. I really appreciate it.
Using extended Euclidean algorithm or seive's algorithm we can get (multiplicative) inverse of a number easily. Then consider that, PK and SK are public and private keys of RSA cryptosystem. They must be inverse of each other i.e. 1/PK = SK. So given the public key (PK), We can easily generate private key (SK). But this is not the case because it takes exponential time to calculate inverse of PK.

In this context I asked the question, is it hard to find b−1 mod n?

Comment: I sincerely apologize, if my question sounds stupid.

Comment: The private and public keys are inverses modulo a number which the adversary does not know.

Comment: @poncho Yes b will be RSA modulus here.